# Work planning and time protocolling tool (preferably with invoice generator)

Tags: linux, time-management, desktop-client, invoicing

I need a tool that works on my desktop (Linux) that helps me keep track of the time I spend doing a task (telephone, coding, going-to-lunch, ...)

The less it distracts me the more I like it, it should have a minimalist approach to the UI.

I cannot plan all tasks in advance, so it must be possible to hit the icon then do my work (leaving the window open) and when I'm finished enter what I just did.

The following scenarios should be covered:

1. I start work in the morning doing something planned (coding)
2. I get interrupted by a co-worker with a question to a different project and need to help him now (I click the icon, leave my place and go to his, return and type whatever I did)
3. I get interrupted by a customer calling (I click the icon enter the name of the customer hit enter, the window goes away. I interact with the customer however and need to add details to the task later)
4. I forgot to click the icon when I started a work and need to change the entries of what I did (that can be complicated, but must be possible)

If I can give the program details like "customer" or "project" and then create from that information an invoice that would be a huge plus, but is not necessary.

The program should export the stored information in some sort of table-oriented data (CSV, Excel, ODS, whatever...).

I searched for such a tool but didn't find one and am considering writing it myself currently. I prefer open source software but that's not a must-have. If I have to pay for it, the price should be below {20€|25$} / month and there MUST be a payment method different to PayPal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you want to give [Hamster](http://projecthamster.wordpress.com/) a try.
Although I never used it at work, it has a minimal GUI, it is easy to switch a task and you can export to some formats.

With the invoice, I am not that sure if you can realize it. But it has some overview functionality, with which you can filter your tasks and then export it to a file. Perhaps you can use that exported file as a basis for your invoice.

Some Screenshots:

The main window

[image: Main Window]

It is possible to add an earlier task during the time, where another task is.

[image: Adding an earlier task]

The added phone call can be seen.

[image: Hamster - Time Tracker Screen]

Comment: (Just FYI: testing the software will take a while, I can't currently start gnome applets in my xfce panel)

Comment: I tried it. Works good. Userinterface is a bit bloated but I think I can fix that (when I find time).